# yield from asyncio.sleep works, but yield from async def fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-3.6

The following code works fine:

```
import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
async def a ():
    print('hello')
def b ():
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
loop.run_until_complete(b())
loop.close()
print('done')
```

But, the following fails:

```
import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
async def a ():
    print('hello')
def b ():
    yield from a() # <=========== only 1 tiny change
loop.run_until_complete(b())
loop.close()
print('done')
```

Decorating `b` with `@asyncio.coroutine` makes it work.

But, the question is why does the first piece of code work fine without the `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator? The docs clearly say that `asyncio.sleep` is a coroutine, and so is `a`, so why does the code fail in one case and work fine for the other case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code produces the following error:

```
...
        yield from a()  # <=========== only 1 tiny change
TypeError: cannot 'yield from' a coroutine object in a non-coroutine generator
```

As clearly stated in the error message, when using asyncio, you should either use `@coroutine` or `async def` to mark your coroutines.  In `async def`s, `await` should be used instead of `yield from`:

```
import asyncio


async def a():
    print('hello')


async def b():
    await a()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(b())
loop.close()
print('done')
```

or, for python 3.4:

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def a():
    print('hello')


@asyncio.coroutine
def b():
    yield from a()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(b())
loop.close()

print('done')
```

Your first example is considered "buggy", but it is executing "properly" because `run_until_complete` calls [`iscoroutine`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/asyncio/coroutines.py#L268) which currently returns True for generators (any `def` with a `yield`/`yield from`), but this is an implementation detail that might change in a future version of python.  Using `@couroutine` on `def a()` (instead of `async def a()`), or even just adding `yield from asyncio.sleep(1)` to a regular `def a()`  would make your second example run as well.  Currently python might be "merciful" when using generators which are not marked as coroutines in asyncio, but not when using `async defs`.

Comment: thanks @udi here's another puzzle that might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708609/unfair-scheduling-bad-lock-optimization-in-asyncio-event-loop