# Bad lock optimization in asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, python-asyncio, python-3.6

**Update: Edited title to focus on the main problem. See my answer for full update.**

In the following code, `a()` and `b()` are identical. Each of them counts from 0 to 9 concurrently while acquiring and yielding a lock every 2 counts.

```
import asyncio

lock = asyncio.Lock()

def a ():
 yield from lock.acquire()
 for i in range(10):
  print('a: ' + str(i))
  if i % 2 == 0:
   lock.release()
   yield from lock.acquire()
 lock.release()

def b ():
 yield from lock.acquire()
 for i in range(10):
  print('b: ' + str(i))
  if i % 2 == 0:
   lock.release()
   yield from lock.acquire()
 lock.release()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(a(), b()))

print('done')
```

I expected interleaved output, but instead I get:

```
b: 0
b: 1
b: 2
b: 3
b: 4
b: 5
b: 6
b: 7
b: 8
b: 9
a: 0
a: 1
a: 2
a: 3
a: 4
a: 5
a: 6
a: 7
a: 8
a: 9
done
```

It seems that the second `yield` does not actually yield but instead reacquires the lock immediately and continues.

**That seems like a bug to me. Am I right? or is there another explanation?**

The following code, modified with an extra initial "noop" `yield`, works fine as expected. That makes me believe that the lock is indeed fair and probably correct.

```
import asyncio

lock = asyncio.Lock()

def a ():
 yield from lock.acquire()
 yield from asyncio.sleep(0)
 for i in range(10):
  print('a: ' + str(i))
  if i % 2 == 0:
   lock.release()
   yield from lock.acquire()
 lock.release()

def b ():
 yield from lock.acquire()
 yield from asyncio.sleep(0)
 for i in range(10):
  print('b: ' + str(i))
  if i % 2 == 0:
   lock.release()
   yield from lock.acquire()
 lock.release()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(a(), b()))

print('done')
```

Output:

```
a: 0
b: 0
a: 1
a: 2
b: 1
b: 2
a: 3
a: 4
b: 3
b: 4
a: 5
a: 6
b: 5
b: 6
a: 7
a: 8
b: 7
b: 8
a: 9
b: 9
done
```

Note that I am doing the no-op yield just once at the beginning, and not every 2 counts. Yet doing so causes the interleaving every 2 counts as expected in the first piece of code.

There is just some optimization (a bug in my opinion) in the scheduler that doesn't really `yield` when acquiring a lock that nobody else is waiting for.

How else to explain the first output?

Comment: I believe this is a bug in the asyncio lock implementation. There should be a `yield` before this line: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/locks.py#L171

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Udi I am just learning asyncio and this looks like an implementation problem. My github issue might clarify a bit more: https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/486

Comment: If you are getting into asyncio, try solving IO bound problems.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you consider this a "bad" optimization? Uncontended locks should operate with minimal overhead (e.g. CPython's `threading.Lock()` doesn't release the GIL if it's able to acquire the lock immediately). The point of `asyncio.Lock` is to ensure that *if* you yield back to event loop while holding the lock, no one else can acquire the lock while you're awaiting something. If you actually did something concurrent in your coroutine, the lock would matter, but you don't (nothing is awaited while the lock is held), so the lock never matters.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The contention is for the CPU. The coroutine does do something concurrent but it is solely computation, rather than any system call for I/O, network or any other thing. The Python implementors have decided that a programmer cannot have a coroutine yield the CPU no matter how many other coroutines are waiting to do computation. Either I misunderstand the situation and would be happy to be corrected, or it is some kind of failing that CPU contention is considered by the implementors to be an uncontended situation. Please see https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/486

Comment: @user2297550: You misunderstand. The concurrency goal here is to perform I/O related tasks concurrently without threading. It's why the core module enabling all this is named `asyncio`; if you read the first three paragraphs of the module docs, they mention the utility for I/O and I/O related tasks. The whole point of the framework is to do CPU things, then when normal code would block (on I/O, synchronization, etc.), it instead cooperatively hands off the CPU to something else that's ready to go. But if no blocking is necessary, it will always do as much as it can without handing off...

Comment: ...control, because switching between coroutines is costly, and the goal is to get things done as fast as possible, not to interleave execution for the sake of interleaving. You can always opt to hand off control explicitly if you really want to (to avoid your double-sleep worries, you can always add `if not lock.locked(): yield from asyncio.sleep(0)` just before the `yield from lock.acquire()` to ensure you hand off control one way or another), but they're not going to make design choices that slow *everyone* by default for no benefit to performance or correctness.

Comment: I'll note, your bug appears to be motivated at least partially by the inability to check if a lock is currently held; I don't know when it was added, but by the time `asyncio` was officially added as a Python core library, `asyncio.Lock` had spawned a `.locked()` method for testing exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** The following is obsolete in light of my comment ([link](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/486#issuecomment-273622956)) on the github issue. The comment observes that you can use `Lock.locked()` to predict whether `Lock.acquire()` will yield or not. It also observes that numerous other coroutines do not yield in the fast case, so it is a lost cause to even consider fixing all of them. Finally it relates this how a different issue was fixed and suggests that it could have been better fixed. That was the request for a `asyncio.nop()` method that would merely yield to the scheduler and do nothing else. Instead of adding that method, they decided to overload `asyncio.sleep(0)` and "de-optimize" it (in the context of this dicussion of `lock.acquire()`) to yield to the scheduler when the argument is 0.

Original answer below but superseded by above paragraph:

The root cause that the implementation of asyncio.lock tries to be too smart in its [first three lines](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/locks.py#L169-L171) and does not give control back to the scheduler if there are no waiters:

```
if not self._locked and all(w.cancelled() for w in self._waiters):
    self._locked = True
    return True
```

However, as my first example shows, this prevents other coroutines from even becoming a waiter. They just don't have an opportunity to run to the point they try to acquire a lock.

The *inefficent* workaround is to always `yield from asyncio.sleep(0)` immediately *before* acquiring a lock.

This is inefficient because in the common case there will be other waiters and acquiring a lock will also yield control back to the scheduler. Therefore in most cases you will be yielding control back to the scheduler *twice*, which sucks.

Also note that the documentation for lock ambiguously says: "This method blocks until the lock is unlocked, then sets it to locked and returns True." Certainly gives the impression that it will yield control to the scheduler before acquiring the lock.

In my opinion, the right thing to do is for the lock implementation to always yield and not be too smart. *Alternatively*, the lock implementation should have a method that tells you whether or not it will yield if acquired so that your code can manually yield if the lock acquisition won't. *Another alternative* is to have the `acquire()` call return a value that tells you whether or not it actually yielded. This is less preferable but still better than the status quo.

One might think a better workaround might be to manually yield at the time of `release()`. However if you look at a tight loop that releases and reacquires after pieces of work, then it amounts to the same thing -- in the common case it will still yield twice, once at release time, again at acquire time, adding inefficiency.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you are trying to achieve, but it seems like `Lock` is not the tool you need.  To interleave python code, you can do as simple as:

```
def foo(tag, n):
    for i in range(n):
        print("inside", tag, i)
        yield (tag, i)


print('start')

for x in zip(foo('A', 10), foo('B', 10)):
    print(x)

print('done')
```

No need for `asyncio` or `threading`. Anyway, `asyncio` without IO does not make a lot of sense.

**`threading`**.`Lock` is used to synchronize critical parts of a program which otherwise run in independent threads.  `asyncio.Lock` would allow other coroutines to continue with IO while one coroutine waits:

```
import asyncio
import random

lock = asyncio.Lock()


async def foo(tag):
    print(tag, "Start")
    for i in range(10):
        print(tag, '>', i)
        await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 1))
        print(tag, '<', i)

    async with lock:
        # only one coroutine can execute the critical section at once.
        # other coroutines can still use IO.
        print(tag, "CRITICAL START")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(tag, "STILL IN CRITICAL")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(tag, "CRITICAL END")

    for i in range(10, 20):
        print(tag, '>', i)
        await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 1))
        print(tag, '<', i)

    print(tag, "Done")


print('start')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = asyncio.gather(foo('A'), foo('B'), foo('C'))
loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
loop.close()

print('done')
```

Keep in mind that the keyword `yield` does not always obey the English meaning of *yield* :-) .

You can see that it makes more sense that `async with lock` will acquire the lock immediately, without awaiting for other coroutines to do more work: the first couroutine to reach the critical part should start running it. (i.e., adding an `await asyncio.sleep(0)` before `async with lock:` just does not make any sense.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but please take another look at the code samples in the question. If the critical section has async ops as in your example then there is no problem. That is, if the critical section yields control back to the scheduler then there is no problem because other coroutines will make progress. However, if the critical section is part of a purely computational task, then other coroutines will not run even though the first one may repeatedly release and reacquire the lock. See also: https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/486

Comment: I added another sentence to my answer. If your code is purely CPU bound, locks, asyncio or threading will not help you.

Comment: Another suggestion to understand the issue is to try to predict the output of the very first piece of code in the question (without looking at the posted output). Most programmers would assume that the coroutines would run concurrently -- a bit of A, a bit of B, a bit of A, a bit of B, ... But they don't.

Comment: oops, my first example above was wrong.  See `zip()` above

Comment: OK. Thanks for your kind explanation. I still feel there is a problem, so I will think more before accepting.  (With purely CPU bound tasks, threading does allow letting all of them make progress concurrently rather than sequentially, which is useful in some cases. And with threading, one thread cannot monopolize the lock. Without the ill-considered optimization that I pinpoint, asyncio would also behave the same way, but alas the premature optimization gets in the way of good semantics.)